# Will Unity work with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250?

Tags: 11.04, unity, ati

I'm about to purchase a laptop with this graphics card (cheap deal) but I read that ATI cards have issues or may even not work with Natty. Is this true? Is there a way to fix the eventual problem? Are proprietary drivers needed or the included drivers will do fine? Thanks a lot for your advice, if I get the laptop and can't run Unity, it would be pretty much a waste of money to me.

Comment: My ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3560 works perfectly with unity, but I had to install the latest driver from the producer. After that minor issue, everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Just to add another data point, I have a laptop with a Mobility Radeon 4200 (M880G). It runs unity with no problems with the open source drivers. The proprietary driver is still a bit glitchy for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am typing this on a laptop with a mobility radeon 4200.  It is an AMD Nile chipset, and as of Natty, everything except wireless works out of the box.  I had to upgrade to a kernel-ppa for 2.6.39, and then that also worked out of the box.  in 2.6.39, unfortunately, the proprietary drivers do not seem to install.  The open source drivers for the graphics card work, though at reduced performance and higher operating temperature.   When I play Minecraft, it gets uncomfortably hot.   I got an auxillary (25$) USB external cooler (two fans) for my laptop which has solved the problem for me for now.   I hope that oneiric will either work with the proprietary drivers, or have much improved open ones.   My laptop is 11.6 inches, very compact.  This cooling problem will likely not affect larger formats.  Anyways, with some caveats, it works.